# How to interpret this projection matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

The set-up is let $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ be a positive definite matrix. For $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^p$, define $\langle u,v\rangle=u^T \Sigma v.$

There is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^p$. We call this subspace the linear span of $u_1,...,u_m$, and write it as span$(u_1,...,u_m).$ Conversely, any linear subspace of $\mathcal{F}$ is a linear span of a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^p$. The projection on to a subspace of the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^p$. can be expressed explicitly. Let $\mathcal{F}=\text{span}(u_1,...,u_m)$, and let $B$ denote the matrix $(u_1,...,u_m)$. We use $P_{\mathcal{F}}$ to denote the projection on to the subspace $\mathcal{F}$. Let

$$P_B (\Sigma)= B(B^T \Sigma B)^{-1}B^T \Sigma$$

I learned projection matrix before in some linear algebra textbook. But none of them has the exact same form as the above. How to interpret the above projection matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $v \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and you want to find the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto the span of the columns of $B$. Then you are trying to minimize $f(x) = |v - Bx|^2 = (v - Bx)^T\Sigma(v - Bx)$ over $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$. We have $Df(x) = 2(v - Bx)^T\Sigma(-B)$, so $\nabla f(x) = Df(x)^T = -2B^T\Sigma(v - Bx)$. Setting $\nabla f(x) = 0$ yields $B^T\Sigma v = B^T\Sigma Bx$, so $x = (B^T\Sigma B)^{-1}B^T\Sigma v$ and the projection is $Bx = B(B^T\Sigma B)^{-1}B^T\Sigma v$. In other words, the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto the span of the columns of $B$ is $P_B(\Sigma)v$. Thus $P_B(\Sigma)$ is the projection matrix onto the span of the columns of $B$.

Comment: Why $|v - Bx|^2 = (v - Bx)^T\Sigma(v - Bx)$? How does $\Sigma$ come from?

Comment: @Jonathen It's by definition $|x|^2 = \langle x, x \rangle$.

Comment: oh I see. Yeah, in this set-up, the definition of <u,v> is $u^T \Sigma v$. But the usual inner product is just $u^T v$. What is the role of $\Sigma$ here?

Comment: It's called a weighted inner product. In linear regression, $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The projection matrices you may have seen in books are probably of the form $P = B(B^T B)^{-1}B^T$. This is because for a model of the form $y = B\beta + \epsilon$, the estimated parameter are $\hat{\beta} = (B^T B)^{-1}B^Ty$, so the fitted values are $\hat{y} = B\hat{\beta} = Py$.

So the vector of the fitted values is achieved by multiplying $y$ with the matrix $P$. This is a projection matrix because it projects $y$ onto the column space of $B$ where the predictions must lie.

What's not mentioned here is that we're in a context where the weights for each observation are identical and the errors are uncorrelated. (we talk about an **OLS** method, for Original Least Square)

If we consider a more general case where the weights are not identical and/or the errors are correlated (we talk about an **GLS** method, for Generalized Least Square), we can introduce $\Omega = \text{Cov}[\epsilon | B]$, the covariance matrix of the error  and $\Sigma$ as $\Sigma = \Omega^{-1}$.

In this case, the estimated parameter are $\hat{\beta} = (B^T \Omega^{-1}B)^{-1}B^T\Omega^{-1}y = (B^T \Sigma B)^{-1}B^T\Sigma y$, so the fitted values are $\hat{y} = B\hat{\beta} = P_B (\Sigma)y$ where $P_B (\Sigma)= B(B^T \Sigma B)^{-1}B^T \Sigma$

As above, the vector of the fitted values is achieved by multiplying $y$ with the matrix $P_B (\Sigma)$. This is a projection matrix because **it projects $y$ onto the column space of $B$ where the predictions must lie, with a GLS method**.

Comment: How do you define $\Omega$? Any typo?