# Ask a step in the proof of linear conditional mean assumption.

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Assumption: We say that X satisfies the linear conditional mean assumption with respect to $\beta$ if $E(X| \beta^T X)$ is a linear function of $\beta^T X$.

Suppose $\beta^T \Sigma \beta >0$ and X satisfies the above assumption. Then

$$E(X-EX|\beta^T X)=P_\beta^T (\Sigma) (X-EX).$$

The $P_\beta (\Sigma)$ is the projection matrix. The definition can be seen here: [How to interpret this projection matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831759/how-to-interpret-this-projection-matrix)

Proof:

Denote EX by $\mu$. Because $E(X|\beta^T X)$ is linear in $\beta^T X$, we have

$$E(X|\beta^T X)=c+D \beta^T X$$

where $c \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $D \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times d}$. Take unconditional expectation on both sides to obtain

$$\mu = c+ D \beta^T \mu.$$

Substituting this into the previous line, we have $E(Z|\beta^T Z)=D \beta^T Z$. Multiply both sides of this equation from the right-hand side by $Z^T \beta$, to obtain

$$E(Z|\beta^T Z) Z^T \beta=D \beta^T Z Z^T \beta.$$

**Taking unconditional expectation on both sides,** we have $\Sigma \beta=D \beta^T \Sigma \beta$, which implies the desired relation.

Follow-up:By the hint, I let $Z=X-EX$. Then I plug in $Z=X-EX$ into the line $E(X|\beta^T X)=c+D \beta^T X$.

The LHS = $E(Z+\mu | \beta^T (Z+\mu))=E(Z+\mu | \beta^T Z)=E(Z|\beta^T Z)+\mu.$ The RHS = $c+D \beta^T (Z+\mu)=c+D\beta^T Z +D\beta^T \mu = \mu + D\beta^T Z.$

**Question: Taking unconditional expectation on both sides,** we have $\Sigma \beta=D \beta^T \Sigma \beta$, which implies the desired relation. How to get the $\Sigma \beta$ on the left hand sided?

$$E(E(Z|\beta^T Z) Z^T \beta)=\Sigma \beta ???$$

Comment: I think $Z := X-EX = X-\mu$.

Comment: @angryavian I think so. Thank you. Please see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
E[E[Z \mid \beta^\top Z] Z^\top \beta]]
&= E[E[Z (Z^\top \beta) \mid Z^\top \beta]]
\\
&= E[ZZ^\top \beta]
\\
&= E[ZZ^\top] \beta
\\
 &= \Sigma \beta.
\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand the first equal sign.

Comment: In general $E[Uf(V) \mid V] = f(V) E[U \mid V]$. See "pulling out known factors" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties).

Comment: Aha, I see. But in your first equal sign, given $\beta^T Z$ and given $Z^T \beta$, are they the same thing?

Comment: Let $V=\beta^\top Z$ and $f(V) := V^\top$. (Note that $Z^\top \beta = (\beta^\top Z)^\top$.) @Jonathen

Comment: Can you help me answer this question, which confuses me a lot? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834704/ask-equivalent-definitions-of-exponential-family