# Ask equivalent definitions of exponential family

Tags: probability, statistics

The definition of exponential family I learned is from Casella and Berger's book Statistical Inference. A family of pdfs or pmfs is called an exponential family if it can be expressed as $$f(x|\boldsymbol{\theta}) = h(x)c(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \exp \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} w_{i}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) t_{i}(x) \right)$$

Recently, I see another definition of exponential family, which is more concise. But I am not sure how to see they are equivalent.

Let Y be a random variable that takes values in $(\Omega_Y, \mathcal{F}_Y).$ We say that the distribution of Y belongs to an exponential family if the probability density function (p.d.f.) of Y has the form $c(\boldsymbol{\theta})e^{\boldsymbol{\theta} y}$ with respect to some $\sigma$- finite measure $\nu$ on $\Omega_Y$. This can be rewritten as

$$e^{\boldsymbol{\theta}y-b(\boldsymbol{\theta})},$$ where $b(\boldsymbol{\theta})=-\log c(\boldsymbol{\theta})$.

Question 1: how to interpret "with respect to some $\sigma$- finite measure $\nu$ on $\Omega_Y$"? I currently omit it because I think it's too technical. But if someone can give an easy explanation, I am very glad to learn it.

Question 2: how to see the second definition is saying the same thing? I understand in the first definition, $h(x)$ can be dropped, since it is just a constant that needs to be integrated to be 1. But it's not obvious for me to see the other part are corresponding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The definition in Casella/Berger is for a [vector parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Vector_parameter), while the second definition is for a [scalar parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Scalar_parameter). To help see the correspondence, take the Casella/Berger definition with $\theta$ being a scalar and $k=1$.
- If $w(\theta)=\theta$, the family is said to be in "canonical form," and if furthermore $t(x)=x$, the family is said to be a special case called a "natural exponential family." See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Canonical_formulation) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_exponential_family) for discussions. So it seems the second definition is the special case of a *scalar, natural exponential family*, while the Casella/Berger definition is more general.